# Defining the principle end of association w/ Code First Data Annotations in ASP.NET MVC EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've followed the advice of quite a few similar questions here but none of them have worked for me. I'm using Entity Framework 6 w/ Identity, and I'm storing additional user information in a separate table like so:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual UserProfileInfo UserProfileInfo { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfileInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SuperiorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SuperiorId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Superior { get; set; }
}
```

where Superior is meant to represent the person who the user reports to (in a business hierarchy). However, when I attempt to do `Add-Migration` for the IdentityModel, I receive the following error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Project.Models.UserProfileInfo' and 'Project.Models.ApplicationUser'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

I was under the impression that by defining `Superior` as the foreign key, I was strictly defining the end of the association.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: EF does not support 1:1 mappings like that, if you want a 1:1 mapping between objects they need to use a shared primary key (both primary keys are the same, and one is a FK to the other as well).  The reason is that SQL itself does not support 1:1 mappings on non primary keys, although you can fake them by using a 1:many mapping with a unique constraint on the many.

Comment: I don't understand how I would use that methodology to fix my problem here. I can't make the primary key of UserProfileInfo the same as the Superior, since then the data user data will be pointing to the wrong user's data.

Comment: I'm telling you that what you are trying to do isn't supported, you need to figure out a different way to do it. The easiest way might be to make it a 1:many instead, but simply just insert 1 item.

Comment: Interesting, ok thank you. I'm thinking then just making it a string and store the ID of the user being referenced, then simply generate an ApplicationUser object when necessary out of the ID. Thoughts?

Comment: By doing that, you won't have any foreign key relationship, and thus not referential integrity.  If you're ok with that, then sure.  Otherwise, as I said, convert one of the navigation properties to a collection to make it a 1:many

Comment: Understandable, it just seems kind of dirty... but regardless, doing so results in the following error: 

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Superior' on type 'Project.Models.UserProfileInfo' is not valid. The foreign key name 'SuperiorId' was not found on the dependent type 'Project.Models.ApplicationUser'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Comment: I assigned the foreign key the wrong way, my mistake. It's now working, thank you!